# Lagrangian in $D$-dimensions in maximal supergravity

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, group-theory, supersymmetry, lie-algebra, spacetime-dimensions

In the paper Dualisation of Dualities. I. By Cremmer,Julia, Lu and Pope they derive the $D$-dimensional lagrangian in terms of the generators $E_{i}^j$, $E_{ijk}$ and $D$, I believe $E_{i}^j$ is the matrix with 1 in the $(i,j)$ position, but it is not specified what $E_{ijk}$ and $D$ are. My question is is it known what matrices they are? And if they are different for each dimension, how can they be derived? Is there more similar literature on the topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scalars in $D$ dimensions consist of

- $(11-D)$ dilatons: $\phi_i, \ i = 1 \cdots 11-D$
- Axions $A_{(0)ijk}$ (call them Type A axions for now)
- Axions $A^i_{(0)j}$ (call them Type B axions for now)

If you go through the appendix in a bit of detail, you see that the dilaton vectors $\vec b_{ij}$ corresponding to Type B axions and $\vec a_{ijk}$ corresponding to Type A axions can be expressed as the positive root vectors of $E_{11-D}$ (up to dualization) i.e. to positive root vectors of $E_6, \ E_7$ or $E_8$.

The roots associated to $\vec b_{ij}$ are $E^i_{j}$ and the roots associated to $\vec a_{ijk}$ are  $E^{ijk}$.

So it answer your question: The matrices $E$ are associated with postive roots of one of the three exceptional groups and they do depend on the dimension.

The $D$ that is sort of confusing here is an extra axion that appears in in certain dimensions, and therefore there is an extra generator. They call this also $D$, which can be confusing. Again, this depends on dimension.

Regarding the derivation: What would you liked to have derived?

Regarding the literature survey: What specific topic would you do you want to read more about? The construction of scalar multiplets in D dimensional supergravity? Exceptional supergravity

I'm happy to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I am studying the 6,5 and 4 dimensional cases and I am curious how these generators can be obtained

Comment: Appendix A of the paper you mentioned tells you how to construct the dilaton vectors. The dimensional reduction of supergravity on $T^n$ from $D= 11$ gives you a bunch of Type B and Type A axions (as in the answer above) which you can arrange into a Dynkin diagram, This Dynkin diagram looks exactly like the Dynkin diagram of one of the exceptional groups. Regarding the roots of an exceptional algebra, there are plenty of notes and books on exceptional groups and a google search will help you find one that you prefer in terms of notation/idiosyncrasies.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes thank you. My question was only about the root generators related to exceptional groups, because I assumed that similar matrices (same definition in different dimensions) were used due to them having the same notation. But now i will look into each case separately.

Comment: @Ash Glad to help! If my answer did solve your question/problem, would you mind accepting it, please, by clicking the check mark below the up/down vote?